# Twilio Studio Messaging Flow not Ending Execution

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I'm working on a Twilio Studio Flow that writes the output of a few text messages to Google Sheets via a Twilio function. The flow does everything it is supposed to do and sends the final Thank You text, but the execution doesn't "end". Any thoughts on where to look? The second to last function is some code that writes to google sheets, but it seems to execute and goes to the next 'success' step.

Image 1: End of flow diagram

Image 2: Execution still not ended 12 hours after sending last text message 'thank_you'

Image 3: The log of this specific execution that is still active.

Image 4: The log of an execution after I manually end it. It has another line at the bottom. I'm not sure how to make that line happen without manually ending the execution.

[image: End of Flow Diagram]

[image: Execution still not ended 12 hours after the thank_you text sent]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean when you say the execution doesn't end? What are you seeing?

Comment: I edited and added a few more images on an execution still active from last night, even though the last text (seemingly completing the flow) was sent last night.

Comment: Hmm... that's odd and I think your best bet is to get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and share with them the SIDs of some executions that stayed active like that. They should be able to look into why they are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, but I don't know why the solution worked.

In line 66 of this: https://github.com/twilio-labs/function-templates/blob/main/google-sheets/functions/log-sms.protected.js, the example has callback(null, twiml) in it. When I switch it to callback(), the execution completes as expected.